# String aggregate function for natively compiled stored procedure in Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I want to use memory optimization/natively compiled stored procedure features to benefit from performance improvements. So, I guess I have to upgrade SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. Ideally I would like to reuse some of the T-SQL code.

I have migrated some code but previously I was relying heavily on using GROUP_CONCAT() function to aggregate strings which is a custom CLR aggregate function. It basically concats strings (delimited by comma) when using GROUP BY, like follows;

```
SELECT City, dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(FirstName) AS Names
FROM Persons
GROUP BY City

City     Names
London Mark,Scott,Rob
Paris   Francois,Liza
```

But since CLR functions can't be used with natively compiled stored procedure, can anyone suggest some way of achieving the desired output.

I am aware of FOR XML PATH approach to get similar results, but that too is not supported in natively compiled stored procedure.

Also, please note that, I have places where multiple columns are specified in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you can further upgrade to the next version of SQL Server (currently in beta stage, unfortunately) you can use the new function [STRING_AGG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) which is a built-in string concatenation aggregate function. Since it's an internal function, it should work here.

Comment: I think you should check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/6492765